# Calling C function from Python passes over incorrect string

Tags: python, c, linux, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a simple function written in C that acts as a logger to limit the size of the log by deleting stuff from the top of the file everytime new stuff needs to be added, the file is a binary file and bytes can have any value from 0-0xFF. After following some example, I'm able to call my C function from Python3, but for some reason the string that is passed over is incorrect.

```
c
int writetolog(char* pData,int bytes)
```

```
python:
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.CDLL("./filelogger.so")
filelogger=lib.writetolog
filelogger.argtypes=[ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p),ctypes.c_int]
lib.connect()
filelogger(ctypes.c_char_p(b"1234;;\r\n"),8)
```

The string gets passed over as junk when I view what is stored into my log file. The characters that came across were junk.

Comment: From what I can see in other examples on the 'net, the argument type should be plain `ctypes.c_char_p`. To me it looks like `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)` would be a pointer to a pointer, which isn't correct.

Comment: Yes, pick either `ctypes.c_char_p` or `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)` for the 1st argument.